# Unable to add select subquery in from clause with ZF2 and doctrine

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework2, subquery

I am using ZF2 version-2.5.0 and doctrine version- ~2.5

I have three entities namely event, ranking and country as follows :

```
<?php
namespace SampleProject\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SampleProject\Entity\Country;
use SampleProject\Entity\Ranking;

class Event
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="eventID", type="integer", precision=0, nullable=false)
     * @var int $eventID
     */
    protected $eventID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, precision=0, nullable=false)
     * @var string $name
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SampleProject\Entity\Ranking", mappedBy="event")
     * @var ArrayCollection $rankings
     */
    protected $rankings;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SampleProject\Entity\Country", inversedBy="events", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"detach"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="countryIso", referencedColumnName="countryIso", nullable=false)
     * @var \SampleProject\Entity\Country $country
     */
    protected $country;

    /**
     * Initializes doctrine collections, called from constructor in entity class
     */
    protected function initializeCollections()
    {
        $this->rankings = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setEventID($eventID)
    {
        $this->eventID = (int)$eventID;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEventID()
    {
        return $this->eventID;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = (string)$name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setCountry(Country $country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function addRanking(Ranking $ranking)
    {
        $this->rankings[] = $ranking;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRankings()
    {
        return $this->rankings;
    }
}
?>

<?php
namespace SampleProject\Country;

use SampleProject\Entity\Event;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Country
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="countryIso", type="string", length=3, precision=0, nullable=false)
     * @var string $countryIso
     */
    protected $countryIso;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, precision=0, nullable=false)
     * @var string $name
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SampleProject\Entity\Event", mappedBy="country", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @var ArrayCollection $events
     */
    protected $events;

    /**
     * Initializes doctrine collections, called from constructor in entity class
     */
    protected function initializeCollections()
    {
        $this->events = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setCountryIso($countryIso)
    {
        $this->countryIso = (string) $countryIso;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountryIso()
    {
        return $this->countryIso;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = (string) $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addEvent(Event $event)
    {
        $this->events->add($event);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEvents()
    {
        return $this->events;
    }
}
?>

<?php

namespace SampleProject\Ranking;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SampleProject\Entity\Event;

class Ranking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", precision=0, nullable=false)
     * @var int $rankingID
     */
    protected $rankingID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="rank", type="integer", precision=0, nullable=true)
     * @var int $rank
     */
    protected $rank;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SampleProject\Entity\Event", inversedBy="rankings", fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="eventID", referencedColumnName="eventID", nullable=false)
     * @var \SampleProject\Entity\Event $event
     */
    protected $event;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="locale", type="string", length=5, precision=0, nullable=true)
     * @var string $locale
     */
    protected $locale;

    public function getRankingID()
    {
        return $this->rankingID;
    }

    public function setRank($rank)
    {
        $this->rank = (int) $rank;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRank()
    {
        return $this->rank;
    }

    public function setEvent(Event $event)
    {
        $this->event = $event;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEvent()
    {
        return $this->event;
    }

    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
}
?>
```

One event belongs to one country and one country can have multiple events.

One event have multiple rankings depending on locale i.e. (en, nl etc.).

I am using ZF2 and doctrine to get listing of events order by rankings in ascending order.

Internally it executes following query to show events listing:

```
SELECT a0_.name AS name_3, a0_.countryIso AS countryIso_37, COALESCE(a1_.rank, 99999) AS sclr_34 
FROM Event a0_ 
LEFT JOIN Ranking a1_ ON a0_.eventID = a1_.eventID AND (a1_.locale = 'en' OR a1_.locale IS NULL) 
INNER JOIN Country a2_ ON a0_.countryIso = a2_.countryIso
GROUP BY a0_.eventID
ORDER BY sclr_34 ASC, a0_.name ASC
```

So the result is something like as follows :

```
event1 BEL 1
event2 AUS 2
event3 AUS 3
event4 AUS 4
event5 NLD 5
event6 NLD 6
event7 ESP 7
```

But now, I want to display events per event per country. So the output will be like :

```
event1 BEL 1
event2 AUS 2
event5 NLD 5
event7 ESP 7
```

So, I believe query will be now like below :

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a0_.name AS name_3, a0_.countryIso AS countryIso_37, COALESCE(a1_.rank, 99999) AS sclr_34 
FROM Event a0_ 
LEFT JOIN Ranking a1_ ON a0_.eventID = a1_.eventID AND (a1_.locale = 'en' OR a1_.locale IS NULL) 
INNER JOIN Country a2_ ON a0_.countryIso = a2_.countryIso
GROUP BY a0_.eventID
ORDER BY sclr_34 ASC, a0_.name ASC
) as t 
GROUP BY t.countryIso_37 ORDER BY t.sclr_34 ASC limit 6;
```

But, with ZF2 and doctrine I am unable to prepare above query.

How can I achieve this using ZF2 and doctrine?

Comment: Can you post your query builder construction ?